# Accidental recursion using fetch() to load a texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use the `fetch` statement to load a local image and use it in my (three.js) application.  The way it's set up now, I get an infinite loop and I don't know why.

It's a large application so I pulled the relevant fragment out here:

```
var mesh;

function fetch_img(filename) {

    fetch(filename).then(function(response) {

        if (response.ok) {

            return response.blob();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was an error.');

    }).then(function(blob) {

        mesh.material.map.image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;

    }).catch(function(error) {

        console.log('Fetch failed because: ' + error.message);
    });

}

function start() {

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({

        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('loading.jpg', function(texture) {

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);

            fetch_img('test1.jpg');
        })
    });
}
```

The idea being that I use a 'loading' image and then when the scene is created and that is loaded, I load the real image by calling `fetch_img()`. Ultimately I'll be calling `fetch_img()` from a number of places based on user input.

I expect it's something I've done wrong trying to understand JavaScript Promises - can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by a "local" image? `Fetch` doesn't support `file://` URLs. If you mean an image that's _relative_ to your script/page, then that's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

Inside `THREE.TextureLoader`, it's using `THREE.ImageLoader`. `THREE.ImageLoader` creates an `img` element, *and assigns an `onload` event listener to it*. It then sets the `img.src` to the URL you provide it.

When you give the `image.src` property a new value, that event gets fired, and goes to its handler, which is still assigned to the anonymous function you gave it in your `THREE.TextureLoader` definition.

The rest is recusrively history.

To fix it, create a new image, assign the URL to its `src` property, then replace the whole `map.image` with the new image.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the really clear explanation and solution @TheJim01.

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as accepted (the check mark next to my post) so others can see the question was resolved. Thanks! :)

Comment: For some reason 90% of three.js related questions go unaccepted.